# Repeat <video> element as tiles over the entire webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to repeat a  element to repeat itself and take up the entire webpage. I want to make it look like this http://twerkingcorgi.com

Obviously this site is using a GIF instead of MP4/OGG so you can just put the GIF as a background and repeat it indefinitely through CSS. But yeah I just want to repeat the videos to look like that site. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: just CSS stuff like repeat. I think the solution might have to be js/jQuery, but I haven't found anything online yet.

Comment: Great link lol. About this, it will depend on the resolution, so you'll need some JS or a CSS Grid for it to look nice.

Comment: @UTDguy : this is not a free coding service, you'll need to research and come with your own code, then ask for help.

Comment: @Devin I have looked for resources online, and I have my own code on my site. Did I ask anyone to code anything? No. I wanted to know if anyone has ever run across this issue and could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The thing is it is so simple anyone could do. Use percentage widths for your videos, set a min-width, float them, set autoplay and loop attribute to true, and you're done.

Comment: Do u understand how much this is going to slow up the page

Answer (score 1):

One option would be converting the video file to a gif. One website that I have used before is https://cloudconvert.com/. 
  Then in the css write 
background-image: url("testgif.gif"); 
background-repeat: repeat;